# Circular Buttons Group View

Tags: android, android-custom-view

This is a snapshot from an app called "Noom Weight Loss Coach":

[image]

I was stunned by this *circular view* in this app. It can have some buttons (six in this snapshot but they can be more or less) and they can be rotated and have different colors.

I have a couple of questions:

- Is there an existing library that provides this circular view?
- If not, from where you would start if you want to build one? I am just interested in the circular look of the buttons. The rotation is not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recomend to use custom buttons. Derive your class from View, redefine onDraw() for drawing buttons state changes and listen for onTouch events.

Comment: I just followed your suggestion and it eased my work so far. I will share the project when I finish it. Thanks :-)